# PHP Split string between several characters

Tags: php, split, explode

I have a script which records your WAN and LAN IP, but it also has a bunch of unnecessary characters around the printed answer. How can I split the IPs and get rid of these characters?

Printed Answer: `{"ip":[["WANIP","LANIP"]]}`
What I want is 2 different variables, 1 to print wan and 1 to print lan.

I've tried with str_split and explode, maybe I didn't do it right or I can't do it with these, so any answers would help.

Comment: how are you getting these lan and wan address, is it from a json request ??

Comment: I'm actually getting it from someone else's server via @file_get_contents, so I'm unsure how the actual source code looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = '{"ip":[["WANIP","LANIP"]]}';
$decoded = json_decode($json, true); // true means it will format it into an assoc array
```

Then you'll be able to access your wanted strings by simply using `$decoded['ip'][0][0]` and  `$decoded['ip'][0][1]` .

Comment: This did the trick, just had to change $json to return my the variable instead of that text, but worked in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "printed answer" is JSON.  In which case parse the json then extract the needed values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
$data = "{\"ip\":[[\"WANIP\",\"LANIP\"]]}";
$jdecode = json_decode($data,true);

echo $jdecode['ip'][0][0];
echo $jdecode['ip'][0][1];
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I would first strip out some of the unnecessary clutter, then explode:

```
$response =  '{"ip":[["WANIP","LANIP"]]}'; //or however you load your variable
$arryRemove = array('"', 'ip:[[', ']]}'); //specify an array of things to remove
$response = str_replace($arryRemove, "", $response);

$arryIPs = explode(",", $response);
```

`$arryIPs[0]` will contain WANIP, 
`$arryIPs[1]` will contain LANIP